# What undocumented alchemy is necessary to get parentApplication to work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I load an SWF with SWFLoader. Within the loaded .SWF, this.parentApplication is returning NULL.  Been searching the internet for eight hours.

code listing as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application 
  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
  initialize=  "Init();"
  visible="false" 
>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flextrace.Dumper;

        private var txt_event:TextEvent = new TextEvent(TextEvent.LINK,false,false,"next.xml");

            private var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000);

            private function Init():void {
              timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timer_handlr);      
              timer.start(); 
            }

       private function timer_handlr(event:Event) {

         Dumper.info("timer_handlr");

         if (this.parentApplication == null)
           Dumper.info("null");

         parentApplication.dispatchEvent(new TextEvent(TextEvent.LINK,false,false,"next.xml"));
       }

      ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you show some code.  I'm not sure where/when you're accessing parentApplication.

Comment: code for loaded SWF provided above. As far as the parentApp code its nothing special.  The child app is in fact loaded and running after SWFLoader.load is invoked.  Don't know if I need to screw around with ApplicationDomain or SecurityDomain to get this to work.  I have never completely understood those, but if some recipe involving them is necessary for this  then Adobe should make that plain in their docs.

Comment: One other thing - the SWFLoader in the parent App is actually the child of a child Canvas in the ParentApp.

Comment: I'm currently running in a test Django App server on my own machine if that's relevant, but would want it to work if just running directly in the local file system.  It seems like there is so much about Flex that even Adobe itself doesn't fully understand (let alone anyone else.)

Comment: Just tried running it outside the test server, directly in the local file system: parentApplication still null.

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to achieve?  Why do you want the parent application to dispatch an event?  Why not just dispatch an even from the swf you are in and let the parent catch it and re-dispatch if necessary?

Comment: So if I just said "this.dispatchEvent(...) the parentApplication would catch it? Would I have to set bubbles=true?  I am dubious of this but I'll check it out.  Its strange that you urge me to not use parentApplication, becuase that is what you find repeatedly on the web.  People will say parentApplication is returning NULL, and someone will answer by telling them to do something else or misinterpret and tell them to use the top level application.  But as far as specifically what I'm doing, the parent Application has a Text object with an html Anchor tag ... (cont.)

Comment: and I want to simulate clicks of it on a timer, so just set an eventlistener in the parent application that triggers the same event handler function as used by the text object for link events. I then have the child SWF (as shown above) on a timer dispatching link events to the Parent Applcation. Why I have the timer in a child SWF is too involved to explain right now.

Comment: RYAN GUILL: I tried your suggestion - didn't work. I replaced the dispatchEvent call in the code from the OP with the following: this.dispatchEvent(new TextEvent(TextEvent.LINK,true,false,"next.xml")); Were you saying that this should have triggered the Parent application's event handler for TextEvent.LINK? It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RYAN GUILL:  I tried your suggestion - didn't work.  I replaced the dispatchEvent call in the code from the OP with the following: `this.dispatchEvent(new TextEvent(TextEvent.LINK,true,false,"next.xml"))`; Were you saying that this should have triggered the Parent application's event handler for TextEvent.LINK?  It didn't work.

Comment: Actually this does appear to be working now. THis can be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Just as clarification, its an answer to my overriding goal of having the parent app handle an event dispatched in a child app. But its even more perplexing why parentApplication doesn't work in the child.  If events dispatched in a child app are automatically handled by a parent app (without invoking parentApplication) then why does parentApplication not work at all in the child.  Adobe's docs blithely assert that parentApplication is specifically designed for apps loaded via SWFLoader, but then others say only use it with ModuleLoader and others say not to try at all.  Its maddening.

Answer (score 1):

I just was looking through Flex docs and saw an answer on your question, if I understood you correctly:

> The parentApplication property of an Application object is never itself; it is either the Application object into which it was loaded, or **it is null (for the Application object)**.

Since, your calling it from the application, it should be null.

Just a quick link for you about accessing nested applications (I haven't tested the solution yet tho, but still, may give you some ideas): [Nesting Flex applications - weird issues..](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=153542)

Hope, this would help :)

Comment: You write, "Since, your calling it from the application, it should be null."   That's not correct.  There's no other place to call it from except from within an application.  A top level application would return null for the parentApplication property.  An application that was was loaded by another via SWFLoader should return the application that loaded it.  parentApplication must be a very rarely used feature,  that must be why Adobe doesn't bother debugging it. I don't know how so few people could use it or understand it. I'll take a look at that link you provided, thanks

Comment: Antenka - I did read the OP of that thread you posted - actually I read it earlier. I can't make heads or tails of it. First of all he says parentApplication works fine for him when he runs as a stand-alone app. Now that right there doesn't make any sense, as the only place parentApplication makes sense is from within a child App (not a stand-alone app). Within a stand-alone app it should return null. ANd then he says when he calls it from within a nested app it returns the top-level app. Now that behavior is nothing like what I experienced (In my nested app it returned null). So ...cont.

Comment: I have no idea what the poster's conception of what parentApplication should be doing, but I know his conception is wrong. And what he says is happening in the nested app (i.e. the top level app is being returned) is what most people erroneously assume its supposed to do (but the poster doesn't like that either). I can read for myself the straightforward Flex documentation  for parentApplication and tell immediately what its supposed to do (i.e. return the application that loaded a child application if called from the child application) only it doesn't do it.

Comment: It should return the parent application blah-blah-blah .. if you call it not on Application object. Your "this" is an application. From my view, the parentApplication thingy doesn't takes in account that it could be more than one parent Application ..
I'll try to test it at my dinner break or in the evening at home and let you know the results)

Comment: Its very simple Antenka: Application A calls SWFLoader.load to load application B. if B references parentApplication it should return A. That's what the documentation says. But it doesn't do that. In fact it doesn't seem to do anything meaningful. THat is why people have erroneous bizarre assumptions about what its supposed to do, and then never use it, so Adobe doesn't even know its broken.  Maybe it works correctly in some very small simple stereotypical configurations anticipated by Adobe, but its broken nevertheless.  Sorry to bore you.

Comment: Hehe .. well, I wasn't arguing with you about how correctly is it working or how much profit this function brings to comunity or how widely is it used. I just shared my point of view about it's documentation (agreed, it's weird that people have different opinions about such things in documentation). But this is what I understand from the sentence (quoted from flex docs) that I've provided to you, e.g.:

Canvas(someObject).parentApplication = some Application;
Application(someSecondObject).parentApplication = null;

Comment: Ok maybe you mean parentApplication it has to be called from within a class or something, not an MXML (application) file. But I've seen examples of it called from within mxml (for those who have magically gotten it to work.) Not sure what you mean though. (edit this is not in response to the comment you just made)

Comment: OK maybe I was wrong, but here's the first part of the doc on parentApplication:"A reference to the Application object that contains this UIComponent instance. This Application object might exist in a SWFLoader control in another Application, and so on, creating a chain of Application objects that can be walked using parentApplication. "  So it talks about SWFLoader and a potentionally infinite chain of parentApplications, i.e. parentApplication.parentApplication...  So a parentApplication can itself have a parentApplication, i.e. the app that loaded it via SWFLoader?  Not sure I care anymore.

Comment: Well, it must be some misunderstanding then .. 
It may be called or from *.as file, or from *.mxml. It doesn't matter. It can be called on any control or container there .. but NOT if the control has a type of "Application".

MXML file is not nessesary to be an application .. it may be any customized component. E.g. if you're extending Canvas, the root container would be Canvas (you have an Application there) and "this" keyword would return a canvas, rather than application .. so you can freely use "parentApplication" method on it.
Can you provide the examples, you're talking about?

Comment: you wrote:"Canvas(someObject).parentApplication = some Application; Application(someSecondObject).parentApplication;"  I don't think that's right at all.

Comment: " parentApplication.parentApplication .. and in the same time - null for the Application object"
Yeah, that's pretty strange .. suppose, Adobe need some feedback on that stuff :(

Why not?

Comment: Antenka, could you comment on this quote: "You can use parentApplication.parentApplication to walk up the tree of multiple applications..." (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_container_3.html). So clearly its saying an application can itself have a parent application, right? How could that happen aside from one Application loading another via SWFLoader (or ModuleLoader as well I guess). That's all I did -had one app load the small app from the OP above using SWFLoader. And then from within that small app in the OP, parentApplication was returning null.

Comment: Antenka - its pointless to have Adobe look at this - It would stay in their bug tracking system for a year without even being looked at and then it would be concluded that how ever it works is correct.

Comment: Yes, it says so .. kinda thinking of multiple nested applications. And now, on this flex-doc page scroll down and read pre-last sentence. "The parentApplication property of an Application object is never itself; it is either the Application object into which it was loaded, or it is null (for the Application object)." That might be some bug in documentation. I agree, it would be better if it was acting like it is said in your quote, but it seems like actually is acting like in mine quote.

Comment: "how ever it works is correct"  .. uhu .. aka random developer feature lol

Comment: "That might be some bug in documentation. I agree, it would be better if it was acting like it is said in your quote, but it seems like actually is acting like in mine quote. – Antenka 3 mins ago" I think you're correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback.  WHich country are you in.

Comment: One other thing though, where it says, "the parentApplication property of an Application object is never itself; it is either the Application object into which it was loaded, or it is null (for the Application object)." I'm assuming "the application into which it was loaded" is the application that called SWFLoader to load the app calling parentApplication.

Comment: :) You're welcome. I'll post a comment to this doc-page .. maybe they, at least, fix docs to lessen confusing :) I'm in Ukraine, you?

Comment: OK a canvas or something - its parentApplication is just the application its in, I accept that. But the parent Application of an *application* is null (if top level app) or if not a top level app, its the application that called SWFLoader to load it. Thats the only reasonable interpretation of the docs. But it may be doing what you originally suggested in spite of what the docs say. I won't write anymore on this tonight.

Comment: Ukraine - that's awesome. I'm in the U.S.

Comment: just 2 cents to add .. just found this one, also had no time to test, but may be helpful: http://thinkcap.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/parent-child-communication-between-flex-applications/

Comment: I actually have used that "parent.parent.parent.parent." he refers to, but its ugly so was trying parentApp, which he also admits doesn't seem to work.  Thanks.

Comment: uhm .. I mean to try the "childLoader.content.application.{public member}". Indeed parent.parent.... is ugly solution, but you may change it a bit to make more flexible. E.g. for endless parents (if no other solution comes), you may create a method, who'll be iterating through parent applications and search for specific parent. To identify specific parents you can make and implement some interfaces ..

Answer (score -1):

Try *FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication*?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

Comment: Would that be the same as Application.application? I don't want the top level application, but rather the parent Application. The applcation calling SWFLoader is itself loaded into a previous application by SWFLoader.

Comment: @Mark FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is the "Flex 4 method" of Application.application.  For all intents and purposes they are the same.